# Vaadin - Altought plugin is installed I can't install add-ons

Tags: java, upload, components, vaadin

I need to use the MultiFileUpload vaadin add-on available at this link: https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/multifileupload , but I couldn't manage to set it properly.
In theory, I just need to put the .jar file into WEB-INF and a window asking to compile the file or something like that should appear... but nothing on my Eclipse! Even though the vaadin plugin is correctly installed!
I must use that add-on because the Upload component vaadin provides is not enough "editable" for me (I need to get rid of the "Browse" button)...

PS: pls no Maven!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recompile the widgetset (client side code). Normally the eclipse plugin finds newly installed add-ons automatically and asks you to recompile the widgetset at the moment you try to deploy to your application server. You might try to refresh your project first.
You can also manually start the compilation of the widgetset by clicking the vaadin button in eclipse while your project is selected. [image: vaadin compile widgetset]

Answer (score 0):

Putting a jar to WEB-INF/lib just includes this jar in the war file. You will not get a compile information.
Since you do not use any build scripts: how do you build and deploy the war file?

Did you add the jar to your classpath?